# Why the return is required at the end of BST insert?

Tags: c, data-structures

I don't understand why the "return node" is required here ?? is it top pop off the activation record from stack or what ??

```
struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);   

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}
```

Comment: `activation record` sorry what?

Comment: Without context, we can't tell.

Comment: Because you have declared the function to return something? If you don't return anything, and then attempt to use the returned value (of which there isn't any), you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). How do you think the recursive call would work otherwise, with the assignments of the returned value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can say that. But more generally you can say something like this whenever your program creates a node (at a suitable position) it needs to attach itself to the tree. Now to do that they need to know about the new node. And this is where the return helps.

Now think, to do that you must return `struct node*`. You declared it. 
But have you noticed that logically only once you need to know about the newly created node and once it is known and added to the tree you don't need to do it. But so what? you have told that you would return `struct node*`. So you are returning it. You yourself commented this `/* return the (unchanged) node pointer */`.

You asked whether it is from stack or ..? Rather than concentrating on the implementation of function call you can safely consider that we are returning from the topmost frame and then the function instance that called it would get that value. It may be a new node or an old node which will be reassigned again.

Answer (score 0):

This section of code is for insertion of a node in BST .return node is required as the insert function is called recursively.so when the node gets its correct position newNode will be called .At that time a newNode will be created and value will be inserted to it , but after that the address of that newNode must be returned to some node-next.